# Pyomo and dynamic objective function creation

Tags: pyomo

I want to iteratively add to a Pyomo objective function based upon rows in a pandas dataframe.  I've created variables based upon the size of the dataframe:

`model.A = Var(range(0,len(arc_decvars)), initialize=0,within=Integers,bounds=(0,5))`

where `arc_decvars` is a list in the same order as the corresponding pandas dataframe series.

What I would like to do is create an objective function like this, but without having to specify the indices explicitly in the code:

`model.ObjFcn = ( df.coefficient[0] * model.A[0] * ( 1- df.coefficient[0] * model.A[0]) ) + ( df.coefficient[1] * model.A[1] * ( 1- df.coefficient[1] * model.A[1]) +...+ ( df.coefficient[999] * model.A[999] * ( 1- df.coefficient[999] * model.A[999]) )`

Any idea on how to do this?

---- Followup:

I am adding a series of constraints like this, one for each node:

```
def NodeA(model):
    k = sum(
        model.ArcVar[i] * node_arc_matrix[i,0]
        for i in model.ArcVar
            )
    return k ==  2*model.NodeVar[1]
model.NodeAConstraint=Constraint(rule=NodeA)
```

Where the 0-index in node_arc_matrix refers to the column corresponding to Node_A.  Instead of creating a constriant for each node manually can I create constraints across both i (arcs) and j (nodes)?

Comment: Concerning your followup, I strongly suggest you to open a new question. Question with acceptd answers doesn't have a lot of attention on Stack Overflow. Create a new question would grab the attention of more users. Take care! (btw: https://pyomo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/pyomo_modeling_components/Constraints.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using Python list comprehension into the summation formulation.

Considering `df.coefficient` and `model.A` have `arc_decvars` as the domain and that `arc_decvars` is in a Pyomo `Set`, you can create your objective function this way:

```
model.ObjFcn = sum(
    df.coefficient[i] * model.A[i] * ( 1- df.coefficient[i] * model.A[i])
    for i in model.arc_devcars
)
```